# Phase space appellation

Tags: soft-question, terminology, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

Does anyone know why they called the momentum-position space the [phase space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) in the first place?

To clarify what I mean a bit more, I'll give you an example:

The name [configuration space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space) for the position space makes perfect sense to me as it represents the configuration of individual particles of a system. But what type of phase does the phase space represent?

Comment: the answer is probably in here http://www.physics.purdue.edu/nlo/NoltePT10.pdf

Comment: @innisfree: curses, you beat me by 1 minute! :-)

Comment: @john, haha, i might have found the article first, but i didn't read the article and find the answer which is the important bit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this article on the history of phase space](http://www.physics.purdue.edu/nlo/NoltePT10.pdf).

Assuming the article is to be trusted, Boltzmann noted that in a 2-D system the trajectories looked like [Lissajous figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve), and the shape of the Lissajous figure is determined by the relative phase of the two input signals. He then used the work *phase* to refer to that part of the configuration that was external i.e. excluding rotation and vibration of molecules. Maxwell picked up on the word and the rest is history.